# Clear an EntityCollection and then Add to it within the same transaction doesn't seem possible

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 entities a Department and an Employee. 1 Department can have many Employees. I would like to clear all the Employees from an existing Department, and also add a new Employee to that same department and then save the changes. It must be within a single transaction.

However when I try execute the code below I get a key violation error on the database. It seems that the clear is not deleting the items in the DepartmentEmployee table, and then inserting the new Employee.

```
Employee newEmployee = GetNewEmployee();
department.Employees.Clear();
department.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
EntityContext.ApplyPropertyChanges("SetName", department);
EntityContext.SaveChanges();
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in one call to `SaveChanges`. The Entity Framework does not guarantee any specific order of operations. So I don't think there is any way to force the DELETE to come before the INSERT without an additional call to `SaveChanges`.

On the other hand, you probably can do it in one *database* transaction. Just do it inside a new `TransactionScope`.

Try:

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope())
{
    Employee newEmployee = GetNewEmployee();
    department.Employees.Clear();
    EntityContext.SaveChanges();
    department.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
    EntityContext.ApplyPropertyChanges("SetName", department);
    EntityContext.SaveChanges();
    t.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it did work for the most part. The only thing I'll add is I had to Load() the Employee collection before clearing it, otherwise when saving to the database the same issue occurs.

Comment: You only need to `Load()` before `SaveChanges()` if your DB has no cascade.